# How do I make my button increment the value of my iteration value and show the effect on the site? (django)

Tags: python, html, django

**views.py**

```py
def create(request):
    choicenumber = 3
    submitbutton = request.POST.get('submit', False)
    choicebutton = request.POST.get('add_choice', False)

    if choicebutton:
        choicenumber += 1
        render(request, 'polls/create.html', {
        'questionfields': Question.__dict__,
        'choicenumber': choicenumber,
    })
    if submitbutton:
        new_question = Question.objects.create(question_text=request.POST.get('question_text', ''),
                                               pub_date=timezone.now())
        if new_question.question_text == '':
            context = {
                'questionfields': Question.__dict__,
                'error_message': "No poll question entered.",
                'choicenumber': choicenumber,
            }
            del new_question
            return render(request, 'polls/create.html', context)
        else:
            for i in range(choicenumber + 1):
                choice = request.POST.get(('choice' + str(i)), '')
                if choice:
                    choice_obj = Choice.objects.create(question=new_question, choice_text=choice)
                    new_question.choice_set.add(choice_obj)
                new_question.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:detail', args=(new_question.id,)))
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/create.html', context)
```

**create.html**

```html
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Create a Poll{% endblock title %}
{% block header %}Create:{% endblock header %}

{% load custom_tags %}

{% block content %}
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:create' %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in questionfields %}

    {% if field == 'question_text'  %}

    <label for="{{ field }}">{{ field|capfirst|replace }}:</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{ field }}" id="{{ field }}">
    <br>

    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    <br>

    {% for choice in choicenumber|rangeof %}
    
    <br>
    
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">Choice {{ forloop.counter }}:</label>
    <input type="text" name="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">
    
    <br>
    
    {% endfor %}

    <br>

    <input type="button" name="add_choice" value="Add choice">
    
    <br>
    <br>
    
     <input type="submit" value="Create" name="submit">

</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I recently added the add_choice button to my template:

```html
<input type="button" name="add_choice" value="Add choice">
```

Using this, I tried using a request.POST.get() to check if it has been clicked, and if so for it to increment 'choicenumber' and re-render the view with the increased value of choicenumber:

```py
    if choicebutton:
        choicenumber += 1
        return render(request, 'polls/create.html', {
        'questionfields': Question.__dict__,
        'choicenumber': choicenumber,
    })
```

Since the increment causes choicenumber to increase, within the create.html the for loop for producing the input boxes for each choice --

```html
{% for choice in choicenumber|rangeof %}

    <br>

    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">Choice {{ forloop.counter }}:</label>
    <input type="text" name="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">

    <br>

{% endfor %}
```

-- should loop once more than usual on the re-render. This does not happen however, and the website renders as originally.

[image: This is how the view initially loads in, and clicking the button gives no change.]

Does anyone know how to make this work properly or improve my code? I am very new to the Django framework, so any advice would be great. Thanks!

EDIT::

**updated views.py**

```py
def create(request):

    choicenumber = 3
    context = {
        'questionfields': Question.__dict__,
        'choicenumber': choicenumber,
    }
    submitbutton = request.POST.get('submit', False)
    choicebutton = request.POST.get('add_choice', False)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        request.session['choicenumber'] = 0

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if choicebutton:
            request.session['choicenumber'] += 1
        if submitbutton:
            new_question = Question.objects.create(question_text=request.POST.get('question_text', ''),
                                                   pub_date=timezone.now())
            if new_question.question_text == '':
                context = {
                    'questionfields': Question.__dict__,
                    'error_message': "No poll question entered.",
                    'choicenumber': choicenumber,
                }
                del new_question
                return render(request, 'polls/create.html', context)
            else:
                for i in range(choicenumber + 1):
                    choice = request.POST.get(('choice' + str(i)), '')
                    if choice:
                        choice_obj = Choice.objects.create(question=new_question, choice_text=choice)
                        new_question.choice_set.add(choice_obj)
                    new_question.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:detail', args=(new_question.id,)))
        else:
            return render(request, 'polls/create.html', context)
```

EDIT 2::

**updated create.html**

```html
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Create a Poll{% endblock title %}
{% block header %}Create:{% endblock header %}

{% load custom_tags %}

{% block content %}
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:create' %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in questionfields %}

    {% if field == 'question_text'  %}

    <label for="{{ field }}">{{ field|capfirst|replace }}:</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{ field }}" id="{{ field }}">
    <br>

    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    <br>

    {% for choice in {{ request.session.choicenumber }}|rangeof %}
    # the update is here: choicenumber -> {{ request.session.choicenumber }}
    # this defaults as 0 though, even if it is defined as 3. 

    <br>

    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">Choice {{ forloop.counter }}:</label>
    <input type="text" name="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">

    <br>

    {% endfor %}

    <br>

    <input type="button" name="add_choice" value="Add choice">

    <br>
    <br>

     <input type="submit" value="Create" name="submit">

</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Have you considered using AJAX to fetch the data for the other choices? This will help remove your incrementation issue. This will also allow you to load the data in dynamically without the need to refresh the page.

Comment: @Lewis I've never tried to use AJAX since I don't really have any experience with it... do you think there are any other ways using Django's framework with Python?

Comment: Sure, I'll create an answer for it.